# ng-repeat/glyphicons not updating for json request

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

What is wrong with this project?: http://codepen.io/susanzell/pen/jWxBjG?editors=1010  or http://codepen.io/susanzell/pen/OMMxOP if the first one is still randomly broken

It's supposed to produce a list via ng-repeat when the page loads of all the Twitch streamers in an array, then when a JSON request to Twitch API is done, updates each streamer.status so each item in the ng-repeat should update with the correct glyphicon or colored bubble if glyphicons just don't work with this. Just for testing I've got two versions of the list and have streamer.status appear as text and I noticed the last item of the list does update and display status, but the ng-class change only takes effect with the ugly placeholder/test classes I created, not the glyphicon classes.

I also couldn't get the $http.get version of the json request to work at all so now i'm using the jquery version.

I'm new to Angular so is this not the right syntax for changing these classes?:

```
    <a ng-repeat="streamer in stream.streamers" href="{{streamer.url}}"        target='_blank' class="list-group-item"> {{streamer.name}} <span class="badge glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass" ng-class="{glyphicon-ban-circle:streamer.status == 'off', glyphicon-eye-open : streamer.status == 'on'}"> </span></a>
```

Comment: You need to use ng-href if you have an {{expression}} for a link.

Comment: there is no `stream.streamers` defined in your controller $scope

Comment: you also need to quote the class name -> `ng-class="{'glyphicon-ban-circle':streamer.status == 'off', 'glyphicon-eye-open' : streamer.status == 'on'}"`